# javascriptでスライドショーを実装しようとしているが、画像が表示されない

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, html

ボタンを押すと画像の動きはあるが、写真が表示されない状態になっています。
画像が表示されるようにしたいと思ってます。よろしくお願いします。

エラー
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```js
document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded' , function( e ) {
  'use strict';

  var files = [
    '<%= @plans.copy_image %>',
    '<%= @plans.copy_image %>',
    '<%= @plans.copy_image %>',
    '<%= @plans.copy_image %>',
    '<%= @plans.copy_image %>'
  ];
  
  var currentNum = 0;
  var prev = document.getElementById('prev');
  var next = document.getElementById('next');
  var target = document.getElementById('target');

  prev.addEventListener('click', function() {
    currentNum--;
    if (currentNum < 0) {
      currentNum = files.length - 1;
    }
    target.src = files[currentNum];
  });

  next.addEventListener('click', function() {
    currentNum++;
    if (currentNum > files.length - 1) {
      currentNum = 0;
    }
    target.src = files[currentNum];
  });

}, false );
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-left" aria-hidden="true" id="prev"></i>
    <img src="<%= @plan.image %>" id="target" style="width: 950px; height: 400px; padding-bottom: 15px; padding-top: 20px; ">
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-right" aria-hidden="true" id="next"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="king">
    <ul class="example">
        <li class="current"><img src="<%= @plan.copy_image %>"></li>
        <li><img src="<%= @plan.copy_image %>"></li>
        <li><img src="<%= @plan.copy_image %>"></li>
        <li><img src="<%= @plan.copy_image %>"></li>
        <li><img src="<%= @plan.copy_image %>"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script src="javascripts/main.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

`/plans/<%= @plans.copy_image %>` という名前のファイルを読み込もうとしてエラーになっています。

JavaScript に直接Rubyの式を埋め込むことは出来ませんので、HTML (ERB) で、以下のようにJSONを埋め込みます。

```
<script type="application/json" id="image-data">
<%= @some_array.to_json.html_safe %>
</script>
```

スクリプト側で、

```
const files = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("image-data").textContent);
```

のように読み込んでみてください。

他にも

1. サーバ側で出力するJSON (等) をJavaScriptから読み込む (いわゆるAJAX)
2. サーバ側で動的にJavaScriptを生成して、それをscriptタグで読み込む
3. そもそもHTMLに含まれる画像のパスと同じであれば、わざわざJSONを読み込まずHTMLから取得するのも手です。

などの方法があります。

**追記**

> スクリプト側のコードは、どの位置に配置すればよろしいでしょうか？

JSONのデータはView側の任意の位置に配置してください。(HTML内に出力されていればどこでも良いです)

> HTMLから取得する方法とはどういう方法でしょうか？

たとえば、対象となる `img` に `test` というクラス名を付けて、

```
const files = Array.prototype.map.call(document.getElementsByClassName("test"), (e) => e.getAttribute("src"))
```

としてください。第2引数はアロー関数と呼ばれるもので、この場合は

```
const files = Array.prototype.map.call(document.getElementsByClassName("test"), function(e) {return e.getAttribute("src")})
```

と等価です。`Array.prototype.map.call` を呼んでいるのは、`getElementsByClassName` で得られるのが `Array` ではなく `HTMLCollection` のためです。

Comment: スクリプト側のコードは、どの位置に配置すればよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: HTMLから取得する方法とはどういう方法でしょうか？

Comment: @some_arrayの場所にこの場合は、画像の@plan.imageと入れればいいでしょうか？そして、const files = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("image-data").textContent);の部分は、var filesの部分を変えて、書けばいいでしょうか？度々質問をして申し訳ありません

Answer (score 0):

画像のパスが間違っていることは考えられませんか？